# Configuring pppd to accept link-local IPv6 address from remote peer

Tags: ipv6, ppp, pppd

I have two Raspberry Pis with their serial ports connected to each other. I have established a PPP link between the two of them and successfully ICMPV6 pinged and opened TCP sockets between them. But I can't work out how to get the 'client' pppd to accept the link-local IPv6 address provided by the 'server' pppd. I am trying to use static addresses so I know the link-local IP address of the remote peer.

On the 'server' I am running:

```
pppd file ./ppp-options ipv6 ::1,::2 /dev/ttyAMA0 115200
```

And on the 'client', I am running:

```
pppd file ./ppp-options ipv6cp-accept-local /dev/ttyAMA0 115200
```

However the `ipv6cp-accept-local` option doesn't seem to work as the [man page](https://man.cx/pppd(1)) describes:

> With this option, pppd will accept the peer's idea of our local IPv6 interface
> identifier, even if the local IPv6 interface identifier was specified in an option.

The 'client' machine is instead using a randomly assigned link local address:

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyAMA0
Deflate (15) compression enabled
local  LL address fe80::fd28:565e:1186:02ff
remote LL address fe80::0000:0000:0000:0001
```

The full output with debug turned on the client is here:
https://gist.github.com/njh/ab3282f43c72dcf6932b3693eb7dfca4

And this is my configuration file (used by both):

```
nodetach
noauth
persist
local
noip
+ipv6
```

I am running Raspberry Pi OS, which has pppd version *2.4.7* installed on both devices.

Comment: It is looking like it is either a bug or a missing feature. I have raised a Github issue here: https://github.com/paulusmack/ppp/issues/256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that there was a bug in version 2.4.7 of pppd for Linux.

The solution was simply to upgrade to version **2.4.9** and I have successfully the 'client' to accept the interface identifier from the 'server'.

Here is the debug output on the client:

```
$ sudo pppd file ./ppp-options ipv6cp-accept-local /dev/ttyAMA0 115200
using channel 368
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyAMA0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7f793cbe>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xb <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xecde7250>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0xb <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xecde7250>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0xb <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xecde7250>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0xb <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xecde7250>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7f793cbe>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x7f793cbe]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::0dfd:3c3b:e130:91ce>]
rcvd [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xecde7250]
sent [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x7f793cbe]
rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xecde7250]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0xb <addr fe80::0000:0000:0000:0001>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfAck id=0xb <addr fe80::0000:0000:0000:0001>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr fe80::0000:0000:0000:0002>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr fe80::0000:0000:0000:0002>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfAck id=0x2 <addr fe80::0000:0000:0000:0002>]
local  LL address fe80::0000:0000:0000:0002
remote LL address fe80::0000:0000:0000:0001
Script /etc/ppp/ipv6-up started (pid 7049)
Script /etc/ppp/ipv6-up finished (pid 7049), status = 0x0
```